# Date not been inserted to database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to insert a date in to my database. But it does not get inserted only the data does.

I am using codeigniter date helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html and the **nice_date function**

> Date helper autoloaded.

My **add_calendar_data** function for some reason just will not insert the `$good_date` to the date column.

**Testing date by echo data below**

```
$bad_date = '1'.'-'.$calendar_dates['month'].'-'.$calendar_dates['year'];
$good_date = nice_date($bad_date, 'Y-d-m');
echo $good_date;
```

And that displays 2016-01-01

> **Question** Why does the `$good_date` not get inserted to the database? And how could I solve this problem?

**Update:**

For some reason even though I can get the year and month on the index function and echo it fine. Will not let me pass the year and month to another through to another function

Controller

```
<?php

class Calendar extends MX_Controller {

    public function index($calendar_dates = null) {
        $this->load->model('dashboard/model_calendar');

        $bad_date = '1'.'-'.$calendar_dates['month'].'-'.$calendar_dates['year'];
        $good_date = nice_date($bad_date, 'Y-d-m');
        echo $good_date;

        // And that displays 2016-01-01           

        if ($this->input->post('day')) {

            $bad_date = $this->input->post('day').'-'.$calendar_dates['month'].'-'.$calendar_dates['year'];

            $this->add_calendar_data($bad_date);

        }

        $data['calendar'] = $this->model_calendar->generate($calendar_dates['year'], $calendar_dates['month']);

        $this->load->view('dashboard/calender_view', $data);
    }

    public function add_calendar_data($bad_date) {
        $good_date = nice_date($bad_date, 'Y-d-m');

        $calendar_data = array(
            'date'=> $good_date,
            'data' => $this->input->post('data')
        );

        $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'calendar', $calendar_data);
    }

}
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.calendar .day').click(function() {

        day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
        day_data = prompt('Enter Stuff', $(this).find('.content').html());

        if (day_data != null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'dashboard/calendar',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    day: day_num,
                    data: day_data
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    location.reload();
                }                       
            });

        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Model

```
<?php

class Model_calendar extends CI_Model {

    var $prefs;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->prefs = array(
            'start_day' => 'monday',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url('common/dashboard')
        );

        $this->prefs['template'] = '
            {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered calendar">{/table_open}

            {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

            {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x "></i></a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_title_cell}<th class="text-center" colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}<th class="text-right"><a href="{next_url}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

            {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

            {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
            {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

            {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td class="day">{/cal_cell_start}

            {cal_cell_content}
                <div class="day_num">{day}<span class="label label-danger" style="margin-left: 10px;">Notice</span></div>
                <div class="content">{content}</div>
            {/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}
                <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
                <div class="content">{content}</div>
            {/cal_cell_content_today}

            {cal_cell_no_content}<div class="day_num">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="day_num highlight">{day} <span class="label label-success">Current Day</span></div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
        ';
    }

    public function delete() {
        $this->db->where('data', " ");
        $this->db->delete($this->db->dbprefix . 'calendar');

    }

    public function get_calendar_data($year, $month) {
        $this->db->select('date, data');
        $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'calendar');
        $this->db->like('date', "$year-$month", 'after');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $cel_data = array();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $cel_data[substr($row->date, 8,2)] = $row->data;
        }

        return $cel_data;
    }

    public function generate($year, $month) {
        $cel_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year, $month);

        $this->load->library('calendar', $this->prefs);

        return $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $cel_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is $this->input->post('data') ? could you add your jQuery code also $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'calendar', $calendar_data); is wrong try $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix('calendar'), $calendar_data);

Comment: The $this->input->post('data') that gets any message I type in calendar. and $this->input->post('day') gets the selected day.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to work with a function variable which is null try

```
class Calendar extends MX_Controller {

    public function index($calendar_dates = null) {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('dashboard/model_calendar');

        $bad_date = '1'.'-'.$calendar_dates['month'].'-'.$calendar_dates['year'];
        $good_date = nice_date($bad_date, 'Y-d-m');
        echo $good_date;
        $this->session->set_flashdata('good_date', $good_date); //Store the variable

        // And that displays 2016-01-01           

        if ($this->input->post('day')) {

            $bad_date = $this->input->post('day').'-'.$calendar_dates['month'].'-'.$calendar_dates['year'];

            $this->add_calendar_data($bad_date);

        }

        $data['calendar'] = $this->model_calendar->generate($calendar_dates['year'], $calendar_dates['month']);

        $this->load->view('dashboard/calender_view', $data);
    }

    public function add_calendar_data() {

        $calendar_data = array(
            'date'=> $this->session->flashdata('good_date'),
            'data' => $this->input->post('data')
        );

        $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'calendar', $calendar_data);
    }

}
```

Comment: This $this->input->post('day') only get's selected day does not give the month or year just day.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 it gets the day_num from the jQuery post. what else you are trying to insert?

Comment: Will give it ago. but found out some reason even though I can get the year and month on the index function and echo it fine. Will not let me pass the year and month to another through to another function

Comment: Maybe you need a single function that will work with the date and return some $var and you can call it whenwever you need it

Answer (score 0):

change your date type to TEXT in your table and try again.

Comment: try making it type TEXT

Comment: and what does `var_dump($calendar_data)` gives?

Comment: `array (size=2)
  'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
  'month' => string '01' (length=2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97934/discussion-between-dray-and-wolfgang1983).

Comment: For some reason even though I can get the year and month on the index function and echo it fine. Will not let me pass the year and month to another through to another function.

Comment: did you `var_dump($bad_date)` in your `function add_calendar_data($bad_date)` ?

Comment: The var dump bad date index function `string '1-01-2016' (length=9)`

Comment: not in index function, in your other function, var_dump it there

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

After working on it for a few hours I had found out why it was not getting the uri segments correct.

When I checked fire bug the form script was not loading correct url. And was missing the uri segments.

> I can now insert the correct date.

```
url: 'dashboard/calendar',
```

Now changed to

```
url: window.location,
```

Full script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('.calendar .day').click(function() {
    
        day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
        day_data = prompt('Enter Stuff', $(this).find('.content').html());
            
        if (day_data != null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    day: day_num,
                    data: day_data
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    location.reload();
                }                       
            });
                
        }
    });
        
});
        
</script>
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Calendar extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('dashboard/model_calendar');

        if ($this->input->post('day')) {

            $calendar = array(
                'date' =>$this->uri->segment(3) .'-'. $this->uri->segment(4) .'-'. $this->input->post('day'),
                'data' => $this->input->post('data')
            );

            $this->db->insert('calendar', $calendar);

        }

        $data['calendar'] = $this->model_calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));

        $this->load->view('dashboard/calender_view', $data);
    }
}
```